# Access DB via VB Scipt multiple row return in "IN" query

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a list of ID selected by client in a comma seperated way in an hidden field eg (1,2,3)
Now i need to retrieve data on basis of these ID from Access DB.

```
select * from Product where ID in (1,2,3)
```

Well and good upto this but in case of duplicate ID in the IN CLAUSE i need to return the count along with the row.
Suppose i have ID = (1,2,1,1,2,5,6) in the IN CLAUSE. The desired OUTPUT is

```
ID | Count | Name | Age
1     3      bcb     45
2     2      sdf     53
5     1      sfg     23
6     1      gdd     12
```

I cannot edit or modify the client side ID list. Just to clarify further the ID is the primary key in the table. I would like to count the number of same ID from the IN CLAUSE and not from Database. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

If the same Id means the same record, then the following will do:

```
Select [ID], Count([ID]) as [Count], [Name],[Age]
From [Product]
Where [ID] in (1,2,5,6)
Group By [ID],[Name],[Age]
```

Comment: This does *not* put the frequencies for each ID in the ID list into Count.

Comment: I may have not understood the requirement. @Sudipto You need the count of the number of occurences of [ID] in the `IN` clause?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. ID is the primary key in the table. So it has only one occurence in the table. Yes i need the count of the number of occurences of [ID] in the IN clause. Is there a way?